# Disable go to report action for a text box if data is zero or nothing in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, action, ssrs-expression

Description

[image]

I want to disable links (`Go to report action`) when data is `Zero` or `Nothing`.

I used below expression in go to Report section:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!HighwayLampCounts.Value)=0, "rpt_Highway_Online_Koli_Detail","rptNoData")
```

But, it doesn't work :(

Comment: why you have written `IsNothing(Fields!HighwayLampCounts.Value)=0` ? do you know what it will do?

Comment: Oh, I found it. It should be : IsNothing(Fields!HighwayLampCounts.Value)=TRUE

Comment: Yes it should be true OR `Fields!HighwayLampCounts.Value=0`

Comment: But, How I can disable link if it is Null, That way I just linked Zero to an empty page. I want Zero Value doesn't have link.

Comment: simply set expression to textbox properties inside visibility.

Comment: I set visibility of TextBox to 
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!HighwayLampCounts.Value)=True, True, False) 
But it hide the Zero items
I want to show Zero Items  with no link

Comment: you should put one rectangle over there and then inside that put two text boxes with condition - and show hide as per condition. that could be the solution in this problem. - Does it make sense? OR use `Nothing` inside expression where you don't want to set link it will work.

Comment: YES.. It worked fine... Thank you very much...

Comment: you're welcome. btw what you tried at last? you can answer to your own question here, so it can helps to other. thanks

Comment: =IIf(IsNothing(Fields!HighwayLampCounts.Value) = True, Nothing, "rpt_Highway_Online_Koli_Detail")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better way! Using **Nothing** in Go to Report works...
Use below expression in *S*pecify a report:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!HighwayLampCounts.Value) = True, Nothing, "rpt_Highway_Online_Koli_Detail")
```

This way link would be eliminated from **Null** Values...

Comment: Thanks! This disables the link cursor/action, plus also e.g. a dummy underlined space that it seemed to insist on showing. So this works and is far easier and cleaner than the other method. You should mark this as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

You should put one rectangle over there and then inside that put two text boxes with condition - and show hide as per condition. that could be the solution in this problem.

Many Thanks to [**rajeshpanchal**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156018/rajeshpanchal)

Comment: happy coding... Nice answer ;-)

Comment: now you can accept your own answer as a correct answer.